# UI update from server

Tags: extjs, gxt

For a desktop-like app where a lot of interactions are needed between components, can still ExtJS be a better way than Ext GWT?

What is the point where you decide to use Ext GWT instead of ExtJS?

My current arguments for ExtJS is that it's much faster than ExtGWT for apps where you don't need the server to interact with the client like feed viewers, forum browsers, etc. - where there is no need for the server to make complex updates to the client.

A complex scenario that I'm not sure ExtJS is better than Ext GWT is a tree with lots of nodes and a data grid. The user clicks a button and the server will decide which components to update: the tree or/and the data grid by inserting some items in the tree or the grid(the client can't know which components will be updated, only the server knows).

For this, I'd make the server serialize some actions(like addTreeItem or addGridRow) that must be executed by the client on success method. The server could also create new components after this request, so there could be "createComponent" with the serialized HTML coming from server.

So, by using ExtJS, whole components must be serialized and sent for instantiation to client(but this can be SLOW - see http://blog.extjs.eu/philosophy/experience-ext-component-loading-can-be-slow/). Given this, is still ExtJS a better way to go?

The main target is having a fast and responsive application, but not reinventing the wheel.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, by using ExtJS, whole components must be serialized and sent for instantiation to client(but this can be SLOW - see http://blog.extjs.eu/philosophy/experience-ext-component-loading-can-be-slow/).

You misinterpreted that article -- the point is he's saying NOT to do that. Sending components from the server can be done in certain circumstances, but is not typical or recommended.

Regarding Ext JS vs GWT, you're comparing apples to oranges. If you are a Java dev, go with GWT. If you are a JS dev go with Ext JS. Ultimately they both end up as JS/CSS on the client -- if they both have the widgets and functionality you need choose the environment you'll be most productive in. If it still doesn't matter go with Ext JS, only because it's usually ahead of GWT in terms of features.

Comment: On the article, he's saying that he went to that company which serialized components and then sent to client in order to create components and that was slow. I know he's saying not to do that, but he also doesn't say what to do and I didn't find or have any idea of a better way for dynamically creating client components or dynamically changing existing client components using *ExtJS*.

Comment: All the above(dynamically changing/creating components from server) already exists in ExtGWT. I am a Java Dev, I already know Javascript/ExtJS and I wouldn't mind to go with Ext-GWT but I worry about it's performance compared to ExtJS. Please see this *big* app demo which is built with ExtGWT: http://demo.openkm.com/OpenKM/com.openkm.frontend.Main/index.jsp - I think it works slow when doing tree updates(renaming, moving items) but I can't imagine how it would work if it were done in ExtJS.

Comment: I can't comment on the specifics of how some third-party app was created. In general, aside from Google's JS optimizations in GWT that might actually make the Ext GWT version faster for certain things, there's no systemic reason why one would be noticeably faster than the other. Again, ultimately you're dealing with JS either way. If you find yourself generating components server-side and sending them over the wire, then you are almost certainly following a poor app design. (I have seen it done when components had to be truly customized at runtime, but that is not a typical use case)

Comment: As above, I'm not sending components over the wire - I also think this is a poor design, but I don't know a better way to do it in ExtJS. However, in Ext-GWT this is by design implemented because any changes you do on server to the components, are reflected on the browser automatically. So normally, I'd say ExtGWT has this by default implemented while in ExtJS I'd have to "emulate" this implementation by making *maybe* a clone of ExtGWT's engine in ExtJS.

Comment: @bmoeskau - how do you handle such cases in a ExtJS app?

Comment: Components are defined in JavaScript and can be instantiated from JS. You should only be sending data from the server, and your client side logic should be able to create any components it needs to. The server should only send what's required for the client to know what components to create.